# Calling Handlebars if helper from a custom helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm looking for a way to override the "if" helper in handlebars to do preprocessing, but then to call the original if helper to do the rest of the heavy work.

If I do this however, it sets up for an infinite loop:

```
// objectCreate is just a function that's supposed to clone an object.
Handlebars._helpers = objectCreate(Handlebars.helpers);

Handlebars.registerHelper('if', function(conditional, options){
        console.log("if helper");
        conditional = false;
        Handlebars._helpers["if"].call(this, conditional, options)


    });
```

Anybody ever have to do this before? I know I can make a custom helper like "conIf" and then call the original but I would like to keep the same name if possible.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it:

```
Handlebars._helpers = {};

// This is what somehow breaks the pointer and stops it from forever looping. 
for(var i in Handlebars.helpers){
    Handlebars._helpers[i] = Handlebars.helpers[i];
}


Handlebars.registerHelper('if', function(conditional, options){
    return Handlebars._helpers["if"].call(Handlebars, conditional, options);
});
```